# Combo box update in asp

Tags: asp-classic

what i want to do here is to load the pictures based on the option selected in the combo box. But when i am selecting "2011" from the combo box after the page reload the selected option is 2012 again..plz help me out....
THIS IS MY ASP CODE

```
!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html><
<head><title>Sinhgad Alumni</title>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme/gallery.css">
<body>
<%dim conn,rs,alumniyear,rs2
 Response.write(alumniyear)
    Set conn=Server.createObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs=Server.createObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set rs2 = server.createObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    conn.open="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" &Server.MapPath("alumni.mdb") & ""
    rs.open "select * from alumni",conn
    %>
<div id="maincontent">
<div class="show">
<form name="form1" method="post"action="gallery.asp">
<h2 style="font:20px SegoeUI, 'Segoe UI', arial, sans-serif;margin: 0 auto;width: 300px;">Pictures of alumni in year:
<select name="drpyear" style="margin: 0 auto;width: 150px;height: 30px;text-align: center" onChange="javascript: document.forms['form1'].submit()" >
<%while NOT rs.EOF%>
<option onclick="javascript: document.forms['form1']">
<%response.write(rs("alumniyear"))%>
</option>
<%rs.MoveNext%>
<%wend%>
</select>
</h2>
</form>
<ul id="gallery">
<%alumniyear=Request("drpyear")
rs2.open "select * from gallery where alumni='"&alumniyear&"'",conn
if rs.EOF then%>
<li><img height="200"width="200" src=<%response.write(rs2("link"))%>></li>
<%else%>
<%while NOT rs2.EOF%>
<li><img height="200"width="200" src=<%response.write(rs2("link"))%>></li>
<%rs.MoveNext
WEND
end if
conn.Close
Set conn =Nothing%>
</ul>
</div>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check inside your while loop building the select options, which one was selected.
Something like this

```
<%while NOT rs.EOF%>       
    <option onclick="javascript: document.forms['form1']"
    <% if (Request.Form("drpyear") = rs("alumniyear")) then response.write "selected='selected'"%>
    >
    <%response.write(rs("alumniyear"))%>
    </option>
<%rs.MoveNext%>
```

**Edit**: updated the code to use Request.Form("drpyear") instead of Request("drpyear") to minimize overhead

Comment: thank you so much that really worked...but can you explain me the code..    **<option onclick="javascript: document.forms['form1']"
    <% if (Request("drpyear") = rs("alumniyear")) then response.write "selected='selected'"%>**
    >

Comment: @user1720452 The addition in the code checks if the posted request value is equal to your records "alumniyear" value.. If it is, is sets the "selected" attribute of the option element (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp)

Comment: hi its working when i am selecting an option from the combo box. but when the page is loaded for the first time. the code     <%request("drpyear").count%> return 0. but the items are loaded in to the combo box.

Comment: hi the code is working great. but the images are loaded only when i m selecting an options but when the page is loaded for the first time nothing happens. an error about "EOF OR BOF might be true" Occurs. when i tried <%request.form("drpyear").count%> it returns 0.

Comment: You can specify a default value for the first page load when no options had been chosen yet... For the "eof or bof" error.. check the rs.EOF and rs.MoveNext in your second loop.. probably need to  be rs2.EOF and rs2.MoveNext respectively...

Comment: yes i have done that... thank you so much bro!!